# Deploying wordpress to temporary url on live server with subfolder

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site that I was working on locally and on a production server. The site is preparing to launch and I have to show the client that it works on the live server before the domain is transferred over. Unfortunately, the temporary url given to me is http://[ip address]/~foldername, so the site isn't working properly because it is looking in the wrong places. The homepage works fine after I put in the site_url and home_url in the admin, but clicking to interior pages is not.

How can I get it working with this temporary url but also still have it work when the domain switches over.  I imagine this can be done with htaccess but not sure exactly what to do.

Comment: Show us your .htaccess file, and did you update your permalinks ?

Comment: Of course, right after I asked this question I just added the "~subfolder" part to the htaccess and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was put in the subfolder in the htaccess file.. so it looked like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~subfolder
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~subfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```